# Alter value of a static field during class loading using a Java agent

Tags: java, classloader, bytecode-manipulation, javaagents

We have a java process that calls some method of class X. Class X has timeout static field which decides how long thread should wait for in case of some error. Now, I want to change that value without changing my java process (I don't want deployment, and this change is experimental). How can I use java agent to change this timeout value to say 1 minute (1*60*1000)

```
Class X {
    ....
    // timeout = 5 minutes
    private static long timeout = 5*60*1000;
    ....
}
```

In short, how to write java agent to change value of a static variable. I have went through some tutorials, but none of those explain how to do this. I do not have access to main method. The project is run by an IOC container.

Thanks,

Rishi

Comment: why not just abstract this out of your code and put it in a properties file? you can then change the properties file during runtime if desired, and whenever your class get's instantiated, it will read the properties file at that time. Also, static fields are not `final`, so with a setter/getter, you can manipulate it's value during runtime as well.

Comment: you can use reflection and access the field http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reflection, you can implement this quite easily:

```
class EasyFieldAlterationAgent {
  public static void premain(String args) throws Exception {
    Field field = X.class.getDeclaredField("timeout");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.setValue(null, 42L); // set your value here.
  }
}
```

Note that this will change the field not **before** but **right after** class loading time. If this is not possible for you to work with, you might also just redefine the class itself what I would only recommend if:

1. Your security setting does not allow you to use reflection.
2. You need to change the value befor the class's type initializer is executed.

If you want to really change the field **before loading the class**, you are lucky enough that you want to change the value of a field that is both `static` and that defines a primitive value. Such fields store their values directly at the site of the field. Using an agent, you can define a `ClassFileTransformer` that simply alters the value of the field on the fly. [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) is a good tool for implementing such a simple transformation. Using this tool, you could implement your agent approximately as follows:

```
class FieldAlterationAgent {
  public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
    instrumentation.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
      @Override
      public void byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader,
                                   String className,
                                   Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
                                   ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
                                   byte[] classfileBuffer)
          throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        if (!className.equals("X") {
          return classFileBuffer;
        }
        ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(new ClassVisitor() {
          @Override
          public FieldVisitor visitField(int access, 
                                         String name, 
                                         String desc, 
                                         String signature, 
                                         Object value) {
            if(name.equals("timeout") {
              value = 42L; // set value here, make sure its a long!
            }
            return super.visitField(access, name, desc, signature, value);
          }
        }, 0);
        new ClassReader(classFileBuffer).accept(classWriter);
        return classWriter.toByteArray();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

You can tell that this latter version requires a lot more code and requires your agent to be packed together with its ASM dependency.

To apply the agent, put either class in a [jar file and put it onto the agent path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html).

Comment: Thanks for this. In first example, how do you get access to X. How is X passed in premain?

Comment: If your class is available on the class path, it's looked up by the system class loader. Premain is passed the command line arguments where you can hand information. Otherwise, hard code it or set a system property.

Comment: java agent is a different jar that has only the transformer class and class containing premain method. My all other classes are in original jar that is running without agent.

Comment: Add your application classes as a *compile time* dependency. The agent class is loaded by the system class loader. Your application is then visible to this class loader. If you are running an application server where classes are not visible to the system class loader, you need to use strategy two where you only name a class as a string.